# How to search for duplicates efficiently?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, search

In my experience the search box in *Close as duplicate* dialog is almost useless.

For example we have a [canonical malware removal question](https://superuser.com/q/100360/194694). Its score is 454 as I'm writing this. It has over a dozen highly-scored answers, including an accepted one.

Yet when I want to close a malware removal question as a duplicate of this one, I can't find it easily - I usually paste its URL into the search box.

- Searching for *"malware"* returns a bunch of questions for me, with the most upvoted one among them being closed with a score of 14. The list also includes a few questions with negative score.
- *"how to remove malware"*: Yields three highly-upvoted questions (>40), but not the one I'm looking for.
- *"how can i remove malware"*: Finally, the canonical question is the first result. But the search isn't very useful if I have to remember the title word for word.

Am I misusing the search box somehow? If yes, maybe it should be made more user-friendly?

What could we do to improve the situation?

- order results by decreasing score?
- boost questions with accepted answers?
- consider how many times a question was bookmarked?
- something else?

Comment: I have most of the common dupes stashed in a notebook

Comment: I am 98% sure that the list of duplicates is based on the tags used.  If I were to hazard a guess, the canonical in question, is likely displayed in the list of relevant questions. [It's the second result](https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=how%20to%20remove%20malware), I am confused, have you perhaps tried to sort the results differently?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm talking about the _Close -> Duplicate_ dialog, there are no sorting options there.